# How to configure npm back to npm default registory?

Tags: typescript, npm, aws-codeartifact

I created an npm package (using typescript and node18 ) and uploaded it to Code Artifact and connected npm to the private registry.

Now I am working on another project and I find the following error whenever I try to commit:

> npm ERR! code E401
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
> npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
> npm ERR!     npm login

If I try `npm login` I get the following error

> npm ERR! code ENYI
> npm ERR! Web login not supported

How can I return npm back to its default registry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following command and my problem was resolved

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```